# Hangfire MySqlStorage - HttpConfiguration does not contain a definition for 'UseStorage'

Tags: mysql, asp.net-web-api, hangfire

I'm trying to use Hangfire [MySqlStorage](https://github.com/arnoldasgudas/Hangfire.MySqlStorage) in Web API app with mysql DB. I installed NuGet package "Hangfire.MySqlStorage" version 1.0.3. When I'm configuring Hangfire I'm getting following error,

> HttpConfiguration does not contain a definition for 'UseStorage' and
>   no extension method 'UseStorage' accepting a first argument of type
>   'HttpConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Seems I'm missing a reference here. Could not figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are calling the method on the wrong object.

It should be, as per the documentation:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseStorage(
    new MySqlStorage(connectionString));
```

Where `GlobalConfiguration` is actually `Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration` from the Hangfire.Core library.

Comment: It seems so. The name is ambiguous. I found this issue also https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/337. Thanks.